# NameError: name 'self' is not defined - when trying to post values to different queues

Tags: python, queue

is this correct way of doing.i am a newbie python

```
class main(threading.Thread):
    queueLock = threading.Lock()
    EppQueue = Queue.Queue(1)
    CrQueue = Queue.Queue(1)
    EPP = threading.Thread(name='EPP', target=EPP, args=(0,EppQueue,))
    cr = threading.Thread(name='cr', target=CR, args=(0,CrQueue,))
    EPP.setDaemon(True)
    EPP.start()
    Cr.start()
    self.send_queue("EppQueue","sss")
    self.send_queue("CrQueue","ssds")

    def send_queue(self,queuename,qvalue,b=None):
        if b is None:
            b = self.queuename
        self.queueLock.acquire()
        self.b.put(qvalue)
        self.queueLock.release()
```

when i run this i get NameError: name 'self' is not defined ???

Comment: Please fix the indentation, it's not readable otherwise.

Comment: That code wouldn't even run like this!

Comment: I fixed your indentation the only way I could possible think you meant.

Comment: @Ragav : was my answer useful..??..If yes, then please upvote it and accept it..!!

Comment: Also, even though it was not your question, there is no need in an extra lock since `Queue` is thread-safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable `self` (the first argument to a class method - you can use any name for it) is meant to refer to a class *instance* (also called an object). You use self where self is not defined, right out in the class where no specific object is yet known.

When the code queueLock = threading.lock() ... etc, is executed you are not in a class object (instance) but in the context of the class, so your lock will be the same for all objects of the class.

About `send_queue`, it's defined and known to all objects via the class, so you do not need to use `self.` to access it.

If you want some code to be executed at instance creation put it in `__init__`.

```
class main(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    self.queueLock = threading.Lock() 
    .. some code ... 
    send_queue("EppQueue","sss")
    send_queue("CrQueue","ssds")
```

Comment: +1. It's also good to realize that `self`, while editors might color it as a keyword, has *no special meaning* whatsoever to the Python compiler. It's just a conventional name for the first argument of an instance method.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: Haters gonna hate... (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use "**self**" for a Class variable / function..You can use "**self**" for an instance of Class...

For example :

```
class A():
    x=3

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=3
```

A.x is a class variable. B's self.x is a instance variable..!!

Also for calling a function of Class..the best practice is to make an instance (Object) of that Class and Call the function with that Object..!!

Like :

```
x = main()
x.send_queue()
```

And for code to be run on "instance" creation, put that code in 
 `__init__():` function

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the `send_queue` function is part of the main class. The `self` is like `this` pointer in C++ and needs to be associated with a class. The `send_queue` function should be indented along with the `main` class

Comment: Wrong statement: and needs to be associated with a class. It should be: and needs to be associated with a class instance.